# lxml etree cleanup_namespaces returns None instead of cleaned tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I wrote a small class for **scraping** a webpage holding some documents inside folders, all of these being hosted on S3. I converted the response into an XML tree, where I need to clean each elements from the prefix URL.

Here's the code and issues:

```py
import requests
from lxml import etree

class scraper():

    def __init__(self, BASE_URL, headers):
        self.BASE_URL = BASE_URL
        self.headers = headers
        self.URL = self.BASE_URL + '?delimiter=/'

    def clean_root(self, root):
        "Needed to clean the URL prefix in front of each XML element"
        for elem in root.getiterator():
            elem.tag = etree.QName(elem).localname

        return etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)
    
    def get_root_folder_names(self):
        "Retrieve the folders"
        res = requests.get(self.URL, headers=self.headers)
        root = etree.XML(res.content)
        print(f"{root}")                  # prints: "root: <Element {http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2016-11-11/}ListBucketResult at 0x8f87b456e441>" 
        print(f"{self.clean_root(root)}") # prints: "None", where it must prints "<Element ListBucketResult at 0x8f87b456e441>"
```

call it:

```py
myInstance = scraper(BASE_URL, headers)
myInstance.get_root_folder_names()
```

If I call `clean_tree(root)` from the `get_root_folder_names` function, the result is `None` as if it was never applied. But `root` does exist just before the call to this function as it gets correctly printed. I get inspired from here: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-call-an-instance-method-in-the-same-class-in-python

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried to use the `clean_root` function without `self.` but then, when I call it from the `get_root_folder_names` function, I got `NameError: name 'clean_tree' is not defined`.

Comment: The term is ‘scraping’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn’t really about calling functions from other functions. It’s confusing pure functions with those that have side effects.

The function [`cleanup_namespaces`](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/cleanup.pxi) returns `None`. It modifies the tree, rather than creating a new one (This is like the problem beginners often have with `list.sort`).

Change the end of the `clean_root` function to this:

```
etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)
return root
```

Comment: Argh, I got trapped like a beginner! :D Thank you for pointing that out in a clear and concise manner!

Comment: Happens to everyone—It’s not made clear in the documentation! I had a hunch, but had to check the source code to confirm.